# Unity 3D: Making a simple capsule stabilizer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Unity, and my C# skills here are nominal at best. I have a simple player controller that I am making involving a player who is a simple capsule. I added a rigidbody to it to allow for more realistic physics, but I wanted to go beyond the basic Freeze Rotation parameters and create some sort of stabilizer that would allow the capsule to right itself using smooth rotation, kind of like a Weeble (for those of you who existed back then)

I tried asking ChatGPT to generate the code, and it generated this code snippet:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SelfRighting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float selfRightingForce = 10f;
    public float maxRotationAngle = 45f;

    private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            Vector3 currentRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
            float angle = Mathf.DeltaAngle(currentRotation.z, 0f);
            float rotationDirection = Mathf.Sign(angle);
            float rotationAmount = Mathf.Clamp(angle * selfRightingForce, -maxRotationAngle, maxRotationAngle);
            Vector3 rotationForce = new Vector3(0f, 0f, rotationDirection * rotationAmount);

            rb.AddTorque(rotationForce);
        }
    }
}
```

This resulted in the capsule tumbling across the level, head-over-heels. I pointed out this problem, and it returned this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SelfRighting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody Rigidbody;
    public float SelfRightingForce = 10f;
    public float MaxRotationAngle = 45f;

    private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
            Quaternion currentRotation = transform.rotation;
            float angle = Quaternion.Angle(currentRotation, targetRotation);
            float rotationDirection = Mathf.Sign(angle);
            float rotationAmount = Mathf.Clamp(angle * SelfRightingForce, -MaxRotationAngle, MaxRotationAngle);
            Vector3 rotationTorque = new Vector3(0f, rotationDirection * rotationAmount, 0f);

            Rigidbody.AddTorque(rotationTorque);
        }
    }
}
```

This caused the capsule to spin to the floor, kind of like a top running out of momentum. Further correction attempts proved futile.

Comment: Weebles were super cool, I loved my weebles.. So. In short you need to find the angles and compare them to "up" as we know on the inspector 0,0,0 is upright, if it shows 20,10,30 then you know you need -20,-10,-30 to push it towards upright..

Comment: I think your main issue is probably that the thing is constantly alternating between the grounded state and not grounded due to the applied rotations, falling back to be grounded etc .. at least that was my assumption in a quick test

Answer (score 1):

I once did something like this by playing with the center of mass. In the end I scrapped the feature, but I still have the script and I remember it worked well, maybe it will be useful for you.

A few notes:

- This was meant for barrels in my game which are cylindrical, not capsules.
- Don't judge my code too much, I was young then!
- I have no idea what this TempCenter function is for.
- Usage instructions are attach this to your object and you should be good to go (I think)

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class BarrelCenterOfMass : MonoBehaviour // keeps barrel center of mass at the bottom so barrels don't knock down as easy
{
    // note - all the initial values here are the ones that I came to after testing this back when I was using it. If I ever want to use this class again, these values are good to go

    [SerializeField] [Range(-1f, 1f)] // Serialized private because changing it at runtime does nothing (if need be I can implement a Set method so it's changeable at runtime but I don't have to recalculate relativePoint * height every frame
    private float relativePoint = -0.8f; // how far along the Y extents will the center of mass be?
    public float centerDotThreshold = 0.5f; // at Dot products below this absolute value the center of mass becomes (0, 0, 0). Otherwise it's (0, height * relativePoint, 0)
    public float tempCenterTime = 0.75f;

    private bool centered = false;
    private float localPosition = 0f;

    private Rigidbody body;
    private Transform tf;

    void Start() // Coroutine because it's gonna turn into a loop where the object's center of mass is updated every refreshRate seconds. Not every frame because that causes weird behaviors sometimes
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        tf = GetComponent<Transform>();

        localPosition = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds.extents.y * tf.lossyScale.y * relativePoint; // instead of doing this calculation of height * relativePoint every frame, I just do it once here
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR

        localPosition = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds.extents.y * tf.lossyScale.y * relativePoint; // just so I can tweak relativePoint in the editor and have it take effect at runtime

        #endif

        if (!centered)
        {
            // finding the dot product and rounding it to 0 of 1 so that if the dot is close enough to 0, it'll equal to 0 and otherwise it will be 1. Where the threshold is is defined by me
            var dot = RoundDot(Vector3.Dot(tf.up, Vector3.up));

            // Changing center of mass to center if the dot is 0 and the current center of mass isn't 0
            if (dot == 0f)
            {
                if (body.centerOfMass.y != 0f) // if inside if instead of using && so that if for example the first condition is met but this isn't, it won't even check the condition in the else statement
                {
                    body.centerOfMass = Vector3.zero;
                }
            }
            else if (dot == 1f) // Changing center of mass to localPosition if the dot is 1 and the center of mass isn't at localPosition (i.e. it's at 0)
            {
                if (body.centerOfMass.y != 0f)
                {
                    body.centerOfMass = Vector3.up * localPosition;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private float RoundDot(float dot)
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(dot) < centerDotThreshold)
        {
            return 0f;
        }

        return Mathf.Sign(dot);
    }

    public void Center()
    {
        centered = true;
        body.centerOfMass = Vector3.zero;
    }

    public void UnCenter()
    {
        centered = false;
    }

    public void TempCenter()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(TempCenterCooldown());
    }

    private IEnumerator TempCenterCooldown()
    {
        Center();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(tempCenterTime);
        UnCenter();
    }
}
```